# How is Chult pronounced?

Tags: forgotten-realms, pronunciation

How is "Chult" pronounced? Is it /tʃʌlt/ or /tʃʊlt/ in [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)?

Comment: Upvote just for the IPA usage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chult, as pronounced by Wizards of the Coast employees, rhymes with cult. I believe the IPA would be [tʃʌlt]. You can hear WotC employees talk about Chult on almost every Dragon Talk podcast from March 30, 2017 through today anywhere you find podcasts or on the D&D website. [This one](http://dnd.wizards.com/play-events/podcasts-livestream-games/justin-ziran-and-kate-irwin-wizkids-miniatures)  has a segment about Chult starting at 7 minutes in.

Comment: Was the video on that page removed? I don't see one.

Answer (score 10):

Chris Perkins from Wizards of the Coast pronounces the name of Chult in the video ["Tomb of Annihilation: Chris Perkins Talks Story, Death and Collaboration"](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/152173106?t=01m29s) (around 1:34 into the video).

He pronounces it [tʃʌlt].

Comment: The linked video seems to have since been made private. Googling suggests the video was titled "Tomb of Annihilation: Chris Perkins Talks Story, Death and Collaboration", and I found it on Twitch here (timestamped link): https://www.twitch.tv/videos/152173106?t=01m29s